# Facing Index out of bounds Error when replacing NaNs in a column using a function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis, missing-data

I am trying to replace NAN values using below function,but i am getting Index out of Bound Error.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZh05.png) is my sample Dataframe. It has columns(Date,Centre_Name,Commodity_Name,Price,Year).I am trying to replace Price column missing values using MODE() of Price based on corresponding Year and Centre_Name columns.

For example for year 1997 and Centre_Name='SHIMLA' I am using below code to replace missing values of Price column and it is working.

```
data.loc[(data['Year']==1997)&(data['Centre_Name']=='SHIMLA')&(data['Price'].isnull()),'Price']=data.loc[(data['Year']==1997)&(data['Centre_Name']=='SHIMLA'),'Price'].mode()[0]
```

But below function is not working.Please help

```
year_list=list(data['Year'].unique())
for each_year in year_list:
    city_list=list(data[data['Year']==each_year]['Centre_Name'].unique())
    for each_city in city_list:
        data.loc[(data['Year']==each_year)&(data['Centre_Name']==each_city)&(data['Price'].isnull()),'Price']=data.loc[(data['Year']==each_year)&(data['Centre_Name']==each_city),'Price'].mode()[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second script replace `data.iloc` with `data.loc`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have replaced data.iloc with data.loc ,but still I am gettinhg Index out of Bound error

Comment: your code will basically try every single combination of year and city, right? but do all those combinations really exist? if any of them are missing, you will get the error that it can't be found, which could result in index out of bound. I think it would be helpful if you would add also the sample data contents to your question